# fetch api in javascript with map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, fetch-api

I am using fetch to get "api.github.com/users" data to show on the screen. I am able to show a single entity but not the entire data. I am new so a bit of detailing will be a great help.

```
const btnn = document.getElementById("dog");

function Cat(){
    fetch('https://api.github.com/users').then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => btnn.map((values) =>{
        `</p>login:"${values.login}" </p>`})
        )}    
 Cat()
```

HTML

```
<body>
    
<div id="dog"></div>

<button id="btn">Dogs</button>


    <script src="api.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: `map` is a method found on Arrays. `btnn` is an element, not an array. The function you pass to `map` doesn't return anything. If it did, you'd ignore it as you do nothing with the return value. There's so much wrong here you really need to start with some introductory tutorials and work on one concept at a time.

Comment: can u provide a solution?

Comment: You should probably be using `data.forEach()`.

Comment: need a workable solution

Comment: well this help me pull single entity                                                                                                             const btnn = document.getElementById("dog");
function Cat(){
    fetch('https://api.github.com/users').then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => btnn.innerHTML= `</p>login:"${data[1].login}"
                                        </p> id:"${data[1].id}"</p)`
 )}

Cat()

Answer (score 1):

You should be looping over `data`, not `btnn`. `btnn` is where you want to display the result of mapping.

`map()` returns an array, you should use `join()` to concatenate them into a string with the HTML you want to show.

```js
const btnn = document.getElementById("dog");

function Cat() {
  fetch('https://api.github.com/users').then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => btnn.innerHTML = data.map((values) => `<p>login:"${values.login}" </p>`).join(''))
}
Cat()
```

```html
<div id="dog"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to add new elements to `#dog`, you can map your data to an array of elements and [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) them

```js
const createElement = (tag, textContent) => Object.assign(
  document.createElement(tag), { textContent })

const btnn = document.getElementById("dog")

function Cat() {
  fetch('https://api.github.com/users')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => { // assuming data is an array
      btnn.append(...data.map(({ login }) => createElement("p", `login:${login}`)))
    })
}

Cat()
```

```html
<div id="dog"></div>
```